# Communicating BigFloat between client and server using JSON in Perl

Tags: json, perl, floating-point

I'm transmitting monetary values between client and server and I'm using [`Math::BigFloat`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math%3a%3aBigFloat) (in Perl) to maintain the precision of the values. My problem is that when communicating between client and server, I'm using [`JSON`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON), and am getting an error when using the `from_json` and `to_json` shortcuts in Perl.

The error says I've not enabled either allow_blessed or convert_blessed. Is there a way enable these while still using the from_json and to_json shortcuts and not have to use the OO interface (`$json = JSON->new->allow_nonref;`)

More generally, what is the correct way to handle JSON communication between server and client of high precision numeric types?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing is probably to stringify the number, and then turn it back into a Math::BigFloat on the other side.

For example:

```
package Client;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Math::BigFloat;
use JSON qw(to_json);

my $pi = Math::BigFloat->bpi(1000);

my $json = to_json { pi => $pi->bstr };

say $json;
```

And then:

```
package Server;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Math::BigFloat;
use JSON qw(from_json);

my $json = '{ "pi":"3.14159" }';
my $hashref = from_json($json);
my $pi = Math::BigFloat->new($hashref->{pi});

say $pi;
```